# Excel Conditional Formatting If Column A Contains ANY Value Highlight Adjacent Cell In Column B

Tags: excel

This seems like it should be easy, however, I have been unable to figure this one out on my own.

My problem is this:

If there is a value in Column A, I would like to highlight the adjacent cell in Column B green. This indicates to the user that no value is necessary for Column B. In addition, if Column A is left blank and the user provides a value in Column B, I would like the adjacent cell in Column A highlighted in the same fashion.

In the sample below, cells B2 and A3 should be green.

[image: HighlightProblemExample]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To treat the columns independently two rules are simpler (only one is both `A` and `B` values are to be the same colour when *either* cell in the row is populated). So please select ColumnB and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1<>""
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then select ColumnA and repeat as above with this rule:

```
=B1<>""
```