# Conditionally color highlight value in Column B based on adjacent Column A value in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Environment: Google Spreadsheet.

What I want to do:

Whenever there is `Value a` in column2 corresponding to `aValue 1` in column1.    I want `Value a` cell to be higlighted in a particular color.

```
Col1    Col2
aValue 1    Value a
aValue 2    Value b
aValue 1    Value a
aValue 1    Value c
```

[image]

What custom formula do I use here?

[image]

I saw this similar Q [Excel Conditional Formatting If Column A Contains ANY Value Highlight Adjacent Cell In Column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942219/excel-conditional-formatting-if-column-a-contains-any-value-highlight-adjacent-c) 
  But this is not what I'm looking for.

I'm very new to spreadsheet and excel. Appreciate any pointers.

**Update** :
There are two sets:
Case 1: `Column A has entry X and corresponding Column B has value of 0`   Color 1  highlight

Case2  `Column A has entry Y and Column B has non zero value.`  Color2  higlight

Comment: Which conditional formatting formulas did you try? How many conditions are there? Do you know them ahead of time? You need to supply more information.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the formulas which I tried. 
Yest I know the condition ahead of time. 
There are two sets:   
Case 1: `Column A has entry X and corresponding Column B has value of 0`
Case2  `Column A has entry Y and Column B has non zero value.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select ColumnB, clear any CF rules from it and: Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=and(A1="aValue 1",B1="Value a")
```

with highlighting of your choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: Sorry I updated the question.
In one case I want the cell to be highlighted whenever it has non zero value so I did this:
 
`=and(A1="aValue 1",B1>0)  `